# How are photorealistic wallpapers and pictures created?

Tags: photo-editing

How do graphic artists who post their works of art on DeviantArt (like [this one](http://mariano7724.deviantart.com/art/Play-with-death-by-mariano-villalba-2014-441291680)) create their pictures? What software do they use and how long does it take to design pictures like that?

Comment: Hi madara, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Kinda easy that image tbh. Collage of googled images or something and then photoshopped into each other.Why do you think there is no higher resolution of his work? I'm sure it's to prevent spotting flaws..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing 3D about these pictures. They are just photo manipulations, usually done in Photoshop or a similar raster image manipulation tool (GIMP comes to mind).

The artist draws from any number of resource images and pastes them together, paying attention to changing colours and showing and hiding the right parts of the source images. Such a piece can take anywhere from a few to tens of hours to complete, depending on the composition, resolution and overall quality.

Comment: Well, that could be 3D modeling of the elements, so it can have a good amount of 3D. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It is a veeeeeery board question.

The first element to have a good image is talent, the other is practice and the other is dedication.

That particular image is not that impressive, but you can diferentiate diferent elements.

1. Backgrounds. The clouds.
2. Objects. The skeleton and the card. The flying rocks.
3. Effects. The fire. Another layer of clouds.

The inustry leader is Photoshop, which you can rent on monthly basis, but you can download Gimp for free. https://www.gimp.org/

The basic idea is take some elements, or photos, cut them and paste them together.

After that you need to blend them, so they look that they are from the same scene. That can take from a cuple of hours or minutes to days if you are not proficent enough.

I do not think it is the case on that image, but some artists model the elements, the skeleton and the card for example, generate their own clouds, etc. That can take aditional days of work. But I do not think that is the case on this image.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comprehensive answer. I didn't mean that single picture particularly, but any picture in that similar style. Anyway, your answer was great. Thank you very much.